# Java Private Integer in a TreeSet

Tags: java, private, treeset

My current task is to create a TreeSet of Integers. 
I am supposed to create it in a way so the inner structure is hidden to the user, so I am supposed to declare as much as possible as private.
In earlier exercises we were supposed to build the tree on our own in which case you could just set the Node Element as private which isn't required anymore now that I am allowed to use the Java utilities.

Currently it is looking like this:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Tree28 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TreeSet<Integer> Tree28 = new TreeSet();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            Tree28.add(new Integer(i));
        }

        //Testing duplicates (shouldn't add object as int=4 is already part of the collection)
        Integer i11 = 4;
        Tree28.add(i11);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Printing TreeSet using For-Loop");
        for (Integer i : Tree28) System.out.print(i + "\t");

        System.out.println();
        Iterator<Integer> it = Tree28.iterator();
        System.out.println("Printing TreeSet using Iterator with While");
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(it.next() + "\t");
        }
```

So the basic structure works and I understand it, but however it is not possible to set the Integer wrapper class as private and I couldn't find any solution using the search function. 
I'd highly appreciate if some of you could explain to me how I should proceed.

Comment: Please follow standard Java naming conventions. Having the class named Tree28 and a variable named Tree28 is very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the point of your assignment is to demonstrate encapsulation. As for the *why* to encapsulation, let's walk through it.

```
public class MySet {
    final Set<Integer> mySet = new TreeSet<>(); //final, can't be reassigned
}
```

We can now create a `MySet` object, which contains our java set:

```
MySet object = new MySet();
//assuming class is in the same package...
object.mySet.add(/* ... */);
object.mySet.remove(/* ... */);
//can't be done, it's final so it can't change! right?
object.mySet = null;
```

Of course, you can even add functionality around your set with methods. For the sake of demonstrating *why* you encapsulate, I've also added the method `#wasAddedPreviously` and the field `previous`

```
public class MySet {
    //...
    final Set<Integer> previous = new TreeSet<>(); //for #wasAddedPreviously

    public void add(int num) {
        this.mySet.add(num);
        this.previous.add(num);
    }

    public void printAll(PrintStream output) {
        this.mySet.forEach(output::println);
    }

    public boolean wasAddedPreviously(int num) {
        return this.previous.contains(num);
    }
}
```

Obviously you can expose members like this, but you can also see how it the problems with public fields can get unweildly when you introduce complex state. Now, if you modify `mySet` directly, you'll notice `#wasAddedPreviously` breaks!

```
MySet object = new MySet();
object.mySet.add(42);
object.add(43);
object.printAll(System.out); //42, 43
object.mySet.remove(42);
object.mySet.remove(43);
object.wasAddedPreviously(42); //false
object.wasAddedPreviously(43); //true
```

To solve this, you try to make your object only expose and do exactly what you want to define that as. You don't want an object with all of the properties of a set inside, you want an object that can add, remove, or print everything, thus we cover that and ensure our fields aren't exposed (by using `private`):

```
public class MySet {
    private final Set<Integer> mySet = new TreeSet<>();
    private final Set<Integer> previous = new TreeSet<>(); 

    //added to allow removing from the set
    public boolean remove(int num) {
        this.mySet.remove(num);
    }
}
```

From here, you won't be able to access `object.mySet` anymore, but all of the functionality you require is there without the dangers of breaking your other methods:

```
MySet object = new MySet();
object.add(42);
object.add(43);
object.printAll(System.out); //42, 43
object.remove(42);
object.remove(43);
object.wasAddedPreviously(42); //true
object.wasAddedPreviously(43); //true
object.mySet./* ... */; // compile error
```

The added bonus is that when you're designing a larger system, instead of keeping track of lots of internal state (using an abstract two-set system for a specific problem?), you simply have the methods #add, #remove, #wasAddedPrev, and #print to deal with. This simplifies your own coding immensely.

Answer (score 0):

You can make anything private within a class but not within a method.  So your TreeSet needs to be an instance field and not declared in main.  This also means you can't access it from a static context as main but your could from an instance method. But for users of your class to access it you need to provide a controlled way of access. So to retrieve a particular value or to print the TreeSet you would need to create a method to do so as follows.

```
public Integer getValue() {
    <return some value here>
}

public void printTreeSet() {
   Iterator<Integer> it = Tree28.iterator();
   System.out.println("Printing TreeSet using Iterator with While");
   while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(it.next() + "\t");
   }
}
```